# How can I re-organize the user account tabs?

Tags: navigation, 9

I have a Drupal 9 site. I can't find how to rearrange or rename the user account tabs.

How can I re-organize the user account tabs?

> [image: screenshots]

Comment: It would help to know which module adds those tabs and see how they appear when English is set as default language.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but the [Tab Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/tab_manager) module may help.

Comment: This module does not work, I followed the explanation but impossible to display the parameters on the page that I want to modify